# Create dynamic table: a section with a heading/label - its related dynamic rows, columns and then again another section similarly

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to create a dynamic table with the below layout when I click on a button (I am unable to attach an image, so showing below sample code which is just an example to get an idea of what I am trying for but I want everything dynamic in the actual scenario).

```
<table>
    <th colspan="2">Group1</th>
    <tr> <td> section1a</td> <td> staff1a</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td> section1b</td> <td> staff1b</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td> section1c</td> <td> staff1c</td> </tr>
    <th colspan="2">Group2</th>
    <tr> <td> section2a</td> <td> staff2a</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td> section2b</td> <td> staff2b</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td> section2c</td> <td> staff2c</td> </tr>
</table>
```

I am using Javascript, Ajax and PHP as backend.
I am creating div, table, th, tr, td tags, using document.createTextNode, appendChild methods but only the last value in the array is getting appended and I am getting something like below:

```
<div> <div> Group1 </div> <div> Group2 </div> </div>
<table> <tr> <td>section1c </td> </tr> <tr> <td> section2c </td> </tr>
```

My actual code:

```
var dvContainer=document.getElementById('dvContainer');
            var div= document.createElement('div');   
            $.ajax({
                  url: 'data.php',
                  method:'post',
                  data:'selectedDivHome=' + selectedDivHome
              }).done(function(groupsHome){
                  console.log(groupsHome);
                  groupsHome=JSON.parse(groupsHome);
            for (var i = 0; i < groupsHome.length; i++){
                var divgrp= document.createElement('div');                
                var grpHomeid= groupsHome[i].groupid;
                var textnodegrp= document.createTextNode((groupsHome[i].groupdesc));
                divgrp.appendChild(textnodegrp);
                div.appendChild(divgrp);
                $.ajax({
                url: 'data.php',
                method:'post',
                data:'grpHomeid=' + grpHomeid
                    }).done(function(sectionsHome){
                console.log(sectionsHome);                       
                sectionsHome=JSON.parse(sectionsHome);
                    for (var j = 0; j < sectionsHome.length; j++){
                        var table= document.createElement('TABLE');
                        var tr= document.createElement('tr');
                        var td= document.createElement('td');
                        var textnodetr= document.createTextNode(sectionsHome[j].sectiondesc);
                        td.appendChild(textnodetr);
                        tr.appendChild(td);
                        table.appendChild(tr);                       
                    }
                    div.appendChild(table);                   
                });                    

                dvContainer.appendChild(div);  
            }
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Ajax calls in `for loop` is a bad idea. When the browser executes the `$.ajax` method it continues to run next lines of codes so right after your `$.ajax` call the browser continues the `for loop` and randomly (depending on network lag and server processing time) the `ajax` result comes back and `done` method will be executed. The `done` method steals the executing pointfrom your `for loop`. So random unexpected things will happen. Keep in mind the followings:

1. An `ajax` call must be the last piece of code that should be executed before it result come back from server.
2. So the next ajax call must be executed in `ajax` success(done) or error function which means after result came back.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Just to confirm, you mean to say to avoid AJAX for this use-case?

Comment: No but use just 1 trip to server. Modify your server to send all of table data in one trip. This work for now.

Comment: Thank you for responding back. I think I cannot do that as per my requirement because, in my further requirement, the second column should be a drop-down list whose values are populated dynamically corresponding to the first column value. To simplify, the second column is like a member drop-down list whose values depend on the first column (let's suppose team values). I guess I cannot fetch all this table data through the id available with the button click.